# Rule for emails that are replies to emails I sent (MS Outlook)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter, rules

I would like to make an alert that triggers when someone replies to an email I sent.

Obviously, I can get most replies just searching for titles starting with "RE:". It would also miss emails where the title was altered and removed the "RE:" before sending.

But this would also trigger on replies to emails where I am not yet an active participant.

My motivation is this:

If I send an email that requires a response, I would like to be notified when I get a response.

Obviously, emails responding to something I initiated are more important to me than just about any other email.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling Conversation view in your Sent Items folder should be able to help you check if your sent emails has been replied. However, as I know, Outlook has no existed option to get us notified for those specific emails. If you do would like this feature, maybe you could post your idea to Outlook User Voice, then other users will could vote on it for you, Microsoft may notice it and add it in the later version.

Comment: Have you got your issue fixed? If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Thanks for your understanding and support.